# datatables.net changes columns width when opening child rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem with [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) .

I have several tables nested inside each other using [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

The parent table has column width specified in the column definitions

```
columnDefs: [{ "targets": [0, -1, -2, -3, -4], "orderable": false },
                           { "targets": [0], "width": "3%" },
                           { "targets": [1, 2], "width": "36.5%" },
                           { "targets": [-1, -2, -3, -4], "width": "6%"}],
```

and it looks like the following after initialization

[image]

However, when I expand the child row, the parent table's columns get resized and look like this

[image]

I don't understand what's causing the table to get resized. It only happens in IE. Would I appreciate any help.

Comment: What html are you inserting in the child row?  Are you inserting a table?  Or a div?

Comment: @BrianKates I'm inserting a table generated manually, and then turn that table in the datatalble.js instance as well

Comment: The column defs seem a bit odd.  What are negative column numbers?

Comment: @BrianKates if you use negative column numbers, it starts counting from the end